# Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online from powersell as admin fails

Tags: powershell, exception, minikube, mingw-w64

Any parameters I have tried running with Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature, got access denied.
as if the PowerShell did not start with elevated permissions and this is although I did start it as administrator:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Access is denied. At line:1 char:1
>   + Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand

eventually, I have managed to run the above from the MINGW64 application. In which I opened a PowerShell cmd(Admin). 
looks like right-clicking and "run as administrator" is not good enough for the elevation

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? Right-click 'Run as administrator' is the default way to run PowerShell as admin, so, what you are doing should work just fine for what you are doing. This means something else is happening in your environment. There should be little reason to use a 3rdP tool to run Powershell cmdlets. Did you try starting cmd.exe as admin, using right-click and starting PowerShell from there or changing the shortcut properties (use the advanced button) to always run as admin?

Comment: I'm using powershell 5.1

Comment: I also tried running directly from program files

Comment: Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.16299.1146
InstanceId       : d77aebbb-55b7-4115-b8e8-ad51e7684ffe
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Answer (score 3):

This is not unique to this cmdlet. 
See this discussion.

[Enabling Powershell Remoting, Access is denied?](https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied)

Upvoted answers:

> The solution came from the following blog post I wandered across:
>   WinRM Access is Denied on Local Computer. In short, run the following
>   from a command prompt (launched as Administrator):
>
> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>   /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
>
> or
>
> Steps to fix: 1) Click on start menu >> Administrative tools >>
>   Windows Firewall and Advanced security
>
> 2) Click on inbound rules >> new rule >> choose the option
>   "predefined" and select Windows Remote Management from the dropdown
>   list >> Click next
>
> 3) Now, Deselect Windows Remote Management compatibility Mode(HTTP-In)
>   and select Windows Remote Management Mode(HTTP-In) >> Click Next >>
>   Allow the connection >> Finish

Answer (score 1):

1. Grab psexec from SysInternals (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
2. Run
   `psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`
3. Inside new cmd process run `powershell.exe`
4. Run commandlet `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature ....`

Comment: This is the way to go for people using SSH/WINRM remote management

Answer (score 0):

Running the below commands resolved the issue for me while using PowerShell v7.3.9 on Windows11 v22H2.

```
Import-Module DISM -UseWindowsPowerShell
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *hy*|FT 
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Verbose
```